# Using NONE ... IN while using a SUBQUERY as NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm

Im trying to get all objects from my Realm Database which do at least have one additional app type (= category) to the given ones. My approach was:

```
let predicateString = String(format: "SUBQUERY(app_types, $apptype, $apptype.name IN %@).@count > 0", hiddenDeviceCategories)
let predicate = NSPredicate(predicateString)
```

Unfortunetaly I receive the error `Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY( [...]"`

Can't I use `NOT ... IN` in a SUBQUERY ?

Comment: The "Unable to parse format string" exception is raised by `NSPredicate` when attempting to parse the predicate. From what I can see the format string you've provided is valid. Is the format string in your question exactly what you're using in your code?

Comment: I added some breaks for more readability. The exact code is
`predicateString = String(format: "SUBQUERY(app_types, $apptype, $apptype.name IN %@).@count > 0", hiddenDeviceCategories)`

Comment: The exact code should be in the question, not hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ladies and Gentleman -

I'm terribly sorry for this question. I was thinking that:

```
let predicateString = String(format: '[...]', myArgs)
let predicate = NSPredicate(predicateString)
```

is fine - but it's not.

Sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, `NSString` and `NSPredicate` both use `%@` for a substitution placeholder but they do so in different ways. `NSString` interpolates a string representation of the object directly into the string, while `NSPredicate` places a reference to the object into the resulting expression tree.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this SUBQUERY("app_types,$apptype,apptype.name !=[cd] %@).@count > 0"

Comment: Thanks for the quick help - but still: `'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(app_types, $apptype, $apptype.name !=[cd] (
    Spiele,
    iPhone
)).@count > 0"'`